# Overloading << sign follow by a boolean expression

Tags: c++

In the main,

```
int main(){
    Data s1(0, 2, 3);
    Data s2(0, 2, 4);
    cout << ((s1 == s2)? "Does" : "Doesn't") << "work" << endl;

}
```

In the h file I overloaded the << sign as a friend.

```
class Data{
    private:
    struct num{
        int x, y, z;
    };
    num p;

    public:
    Data();
    Data(int a, int b, int c);

    //the question is to implement this function.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& outputStream, bool compare);
}
```

Normally, I write the function in cpp file like this (when not dealing with boolean)

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Data& a){
    output << a.data << "data message" << endl;
return output;
}
```

So how would you implement the friend overload function if it's like the "weird" way of writing boolean expression?

Comment: Let me know why you are down voting so I can modify the question please

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. PS. I am not the downvoter.

Comment: A [mcve] of like 10 lines would greatly improve your question. The ability to be able to copy+paste OP's code into my IDE and quickly try it really changes a question from "random snippets of code I have to use my head to solve" to a program I can run in my IDE and debug properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to provide `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, bool)`. The standard library already provides one.
2. Your problems is you haven't defined an operator overload function to evaluate `s1 == s2`. The error is from that missing function.

Update your class by adding the following member function

```
  bool operator==(Data const& rhs) const;
```

if you really need to use the expression `s1 == s2`.

Here's a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Data{
   private:
      struct num{
         int x, y, z;
      };
      num p;

   public:
      Data() {}
      Data(int a, int b, int c) {}

      bool operator==(Data const& rhs) const { return true; }
};

int main()
{
   Data s1(0, 2, 3);
   Data s2(0, 2, 4);
   std::cout << ((s1 == s2)? "Does" : "Doesn't") << "work" << std::endl;
}
```

and its output

```
Doeswork
```

**PS**
Please note that you have to implement the functions properly to make the class useful.